# Why if x ∉ Z*n then the gcd(x, n) != 1? RSA

Tags: rsa, factoring

I understand that if the $\gcd(x, n)\neq=1$ then the $\gcd$ is one of the $n$ prime factors, $q$ or $q$. But how is the fact that $x \not\in Z^*_n$ related to $\gcd(x, n)\neq 1$?

Comment: What do you mean by $x\not\in Z_n^*$.

Comment: I mean that the message(x) is not in the inverse set of n.

Comment: Then what are those elements? An element is invertible iff $\gcd(x,n) = 1$! Did you take a basic algebra course before diving cryptography?

Comment: Meaby I didnt express correctly. I, as an attacker, know the message x and n. I also know that x ∈ Zn and x ∉ Z*n. The fact that  x ∉ Z*n means that gcd(x, n)!=1, but I dont understand why.

Comment: Now, you can upvote, too. Note that you should/follow a basic course about algebra to move on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The fact that $x \not\in Z_n^*$ means that $\gcd(x, n)\neq 1$, but I dont understand why

Let $y$ be the inverse of $x \bmod n$, so that $xy \equiv 1 \bmod n$. That means that $xy=kn+1$ (Bezout identity), or $xy-kn=1$.

Now for any common divisor, $c$, of $x$ and $n$ we will have this; $c \mid (xy-kn)$ this also means that $c\mid 1$, which implies $c=1$.

Therefore, having an inverse requires the common divisor to be only $1$ for finding the inverse of an element $x$.

The converse is also true. i.e.;
Let $\gcd(n,x) =1$, again use the Bezout identity, $xx'=kn+1$. Now take $\bmod n$ on both sides.

$$xx' = 1 \bmod n$$this means that $x'$ is the inverse of $x$

So, we have $$x \in Z_n^* \text{ iff }\gcd(x,n)=1$$